# bindAttr reverse boolean

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

In my view I have a button which I want to be disabled when the data of the model is not dirty.

When I output: `<button {{ action "update" }} {{bindAttr disabled="isDirty"}}>Save</button>` it is enabled when the data is not dirty, and disabled when the data is dirty.

I want to reverse that so I tried this:  `<button {{ action "update" }} {{bindAttr disabled="!isDirty"}}>Save</button>` but now is doesn't check the dirtyness at all. How do I reverse the boolean within a bindAttr helper?

Here is my code:

**Controller**

```
App.SiteController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    isNotDirty: function() {
        return !this.get('isDirty');
    }.property('content')
});
App.SiteEditController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    needs : [ 'site' ]
});
```

**Template**

```
{{#with controllers.site}}
    <div>{{ isDirty }}</div>
    <div>{{ isNotDirty }}</div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
        <div class="controls">
            {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="name"}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button {{bindAttr disabled="isNotDirty"}} class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </div>
{{/with}}
```

I outputted the `isDirty` an `isNotDirty` property so I could watch them change. But only the `isDirty` property changes when I change the value of the text-field,

Comment: you can create a computed property that invert that. You could do something like `... isNotDirty: function() { return !this.get('content.isDirty'); }.property('content'), ...` in the **item controller**(`ObjectController`) and bind to that property instead: `<button {{ action "update" }} {{bindAttr disabled="isNotDirty"}}>Save</button>`

Comment: Try to use .property('content.isDirty')
It should work now.

Comment: This works, but when I remove `<div>{{ isNotDirty }}</div>` it doesn't work anymore :|

Comment: I can't reproduce that. I have a template that only uses `isNotDirty` in the attribute binding and it seems fine: http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/yrj2X/

Comment: isNotDirty: Ember.computed.not('content.isDirty')

Comment: Other handy shortcuts are .none, .empty, .bool, and .alias

Comment: When I change my store to use a FixtureAdapter instead of my RestAdapter the problem does not occur.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution can be found in the [API-docs](http://emberjs.com/api/) of Ember. There is a list of all available shorthand computed helpers.

I used `Ember.computed.not` for this case:

```
App.SiteController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  isNotDirty: Ember.computed.not('isDirty')
});
```